# Retrofit error on Android app

Tags: android, retrofit

I just want to make a small and simple example of the use of Retrofit on an Android application. 
But I always have this "retrofit.RetrofitError" error in my logcat and I can't figure why. 
Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

This is my logcat :

```
    06-29 11:56:03.771    2590-2590/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 249K, 9% free 3202K/3512K, paused 38ms, total 40ms
    06-29 11:56:03.831    2590-2590/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    06-29 11:56:03.831    2590-2590/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a4bba8)
    06-29 11:56:03.861    2590-2590/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: SocialSupaCrew.myapplication, PID: 2590
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SocialSupaCrew.myapplication/com.android.myactivity}: retrofit.RetrofitError
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:394)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at com.android.$Proxy0.identities(Native Method)
            at com.android.myactivity.onCreate(myactivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at com.android.$Proxy0.identities(Native Method)
            at com.android.myactivity.onCreate(myactivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-29 11:56:07.891    2590-2590/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2590 SIG: 9
```

myactivity.java :

```
public class myactivity extends Activity {
    @InjectView(R.id.fullName) TextView fullName;
    @InjectView(R.id.idRepo) TextView idRepo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);


        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(GitHubClient.API_URL).build();

        GitHubClient.GitHub gitHub = restAdapter.create(GitHubClient.GitHub.class);
        //I think my error is here
        List<GitHubClient.Identity> identitiesList = gitHub.identities("SocialSupaCrew", "PictureRepo"); 

        for (GitHubClient.Identity identity : identitiesList){
            fullName.setText("fullName : " + identity.fullName);
            idRepo.setText("id = " + identity.id);
        }
    }
}
```

GitHubClient.java :

```
public class GitHubClient {
    public static String API_URL = "https://api.github.com";

    class Identity {
        String fullName;
        int id;
    }

    static interface GitHub {
        @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/")
        List<Identity> identities (
                @Path("owner") String owner,
                @Path("repo") String repo
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT : I have tried the AsyncTask, but I got this error now

My new logcat :

```
06-29 12:51:37.081    2680-2680/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-29 12:51:38.211    2680-2693/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 213K, 8% free 3239K/3512K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
06-29 12:51:39.761    2680-2693/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a4bba8)
06-29 12:51:39.801    2680-2693/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: SocialSupaCrew.myapplication, PID: 2680
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: 404 Not Found
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:382)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at com.android.$Proxy0.identities(Native Method)
            at com.android.myactivity$Connexion.doInBackground(myactivity.java:49)
            at com.android.myactivity$Connexion.doInBackground(myactivity.java:37)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-29 12:51:43.581    2680-2680/SocialSupaCrew.myapplication I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

My new myactivity :

```
public class myactivity extends Activity {
    @InjectView(R.id.fullName) TextView fullName;
    @InjectView(R.id.idRepo) TextView idRepo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        Connexion connexion = new Connexion();
        connexion.execute();
    }

    class Connexion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args){
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(GitHubClient.API_URL).build();

            GitHubClient.GitHub gitHub = restAdapter.create(GitHubClient.GitHub.class);

            List<GitHubClient.Identity> identitiesList = gitHub.identities("SocialSupaCrew", "PictureRepo");

            for (GitHubClient.Identity identity : identitiesList){
                fullName.setText("fullName : " + identity.fullName);
                idRepo.setText("id = " + identity.id);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Call the network related code from an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the AsyncTask but I think I got an 404 not found error. Is this mean my url is wrong ?

Comment: yes the url has to be wrong then